# Laravel MS SQL Login timeout expired

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx & php-fpm

In laravel I try to connect to a external MS SQL Server.

My .env database settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.20.2.10
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=DATA
DB_USERNAME=saWeb
DB_PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
```

My config/database.php:

```
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),        
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.20.2.10'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DATA'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'saWeb'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

**Laravel got the error:**

> SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server]Login timeout expired

I reinstalled the sql drivers (pdo_sqlsrv & sqlsrv).

I made a file: sqltest.php:

```
<?php
    $host = "172.20.2.10";
    $user = "saWeb";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $dbname="DATA";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
        PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING
    ];

    try {
        $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433; Database=$dbname", $user, $password);


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
    echo"Connection Successful";
    ?>
```

The output is: Connection Successful

Another try:

```
<?php
$serverName = "172.20.2.10";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "DATA",
    "Uid" => "saWeb",
    "PWD" => "PASSWORD"
);


$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

$tsql= "SELECT @@Version as SQL_VERSION;";

$getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);


if ($getResults == FALSE)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
?>
<h1> Results : </h1>
<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo ($row['SQL_VERSION']);
    echo ("<br/>");
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
function FormatErrors( $errors )
{
    /* Display errors. */
    echo "Error information: <br/>";

    foreach ( $errors as $error )
    {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";
        echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";
        echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

The output: `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019091) - 12.0.4237.0 (X64) Jul 5 2017 22:03:42 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

I can connect with the SQL Server without Laravel, what's wrong with my Laravel configuration?

Comment: You have different IP's in those snippets (`'127.20.2.10'` and `'172.20.2.10'`). Is that intentional? If yes, then test against the other instance in your latter attempts. Testing a client against one instance doesn't mean it'll work against a different one.

Comment: Oh my god! That's the problem. I checked it 100 times.. it has to be 172.20.2.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ips in your tests tests 172.20.2.10  and 127.20.2.10.. Probably a typo and the one you have to set in your .env and config/database.php is 172.20.2.10

Comment: You're right! It was a typo... I checked 100 times if my host is correct..

Comment: Maa kasam !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. login to your main MS database. password and name check. Sometimes a wrong password gets the message Login timeout expired.

laravel:
'host' => '127.20.2.10',
or
'host' => env('DB_HOST'),  //env write DB_HOST 127.20.2.10